# Page brings back old session after session_destroy

Tags: php, session-cookies

No clue why this is doing this.  But my logout.php code works fine and redirects to the home page and the session is destroyed.  When I go back to a certain page it brings up an old session I don't get it.

Heres my login file

```
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
   $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
   setcookie('id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 2));
   setcookie('username', $row['username'], time() +(60 * 60 * 24 * 2));
```

Here is my logout file

```
   // if the user is logged in, delete the cookie to log them out
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
     $_SESSION = array();

     // delete the user id and the username cookie by setting their expirations to an hour ago (3600)
   if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {  
      setcookie('session_name()', '', time() - 3600);

   }
   //destroy the session
session_unset();
    session_destroy();
  }

   //delete the user id and username cookies
   setcookie('id', '', time() - 3600);
   setcookie('username', '', time() - 3600);
 unset($_COOKIE['id']);
 unset($_COOKIE['username']);
     unset($_SESSION['id']);
     unset($_SESSION['username']);
   // redirect to the home page
   $home_url = 'http://page.com/';
   header('Location: ' . $home_url);
   exit();
```

Here is the code I have on my page:

session_start();

```
// If the session vars aren't set, try to set them with a cookie
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  if (isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
  }
}
```

This code works fine on the home page, but when I got into a sub directory it brings up a random old session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just destroying the sessions, have you tried unsetting them first BEFORE destroying them?

```
unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

Then call your session_destroy() function.

Also, also, I read somewhere (can't remember where, unfortunately - could be SO, even...) that it's not a good idea to store direct SQL results ($row['id']) in a cookie. It's probably best to store the result in a $_SESSION first, then store that $_SESSION in the cookie.

Comment: I think I figured out my issue.  I had a separate login from a sub directory so when i logout from my home directory apparently that's seperate.  I'll have to figure something out from loggin in from a sub directory